# How we can store JSON object in Redis

Tags: node.js, redis, node-redis, redis-cli

I want to store JSON DATA in Redis How I can do that what is the best option to store JSON in Redis. my object will look like

```
{"name":"b123.home.group.title", "value":"Hellow World", "locale":"en-us", "uid":"b456"}
```

I want to update the object based on value and locale. also want to get this object with any condition. also want TTL support here (that I can remove if not required)

So what is the best way to store this data in Redis without any Memory issue and support all operations with less time?

Comment: You would have to store the Json as a string in Redis, then `get` it again, update the keys you want to update and store the full Json again. To manipulate Json directly in Redis, you could use Redis' LUA scripting capabilities but this is probably too complicated for your usecase

Comment: using string to get an update is complex is there any direct way or using HashSet?

Comment: You can HashSet to store keys and values of a Json into a Redis item but it's not a Json anymore, it's a HashSet

Comment: yes, you are right but I  have updated my format like HSET. need to test String is not good for me. but I just want to know is any limit in the Redis hash set like field limit, field size limit, data limit, etc please let me know?

Comment: to the best of my knowledge there is no limit, it is up to the RAM available to Redis

Comment: Did you check the RedisJSON Module for Redis? (https://redisjson.io)

Comment: no can I use this in nodejs

Comment: Sure see https://www.npmjs.com/package/redis-modules-sdk